# Deleted rows showing in datatable search

Tags: datatable

**After successfully deleting rows from datatable**, those deleted rows are showing again in datatable search.How to overcome this problem.

Comment: What data table are you using and what command you used to delete can you please elaborate as your question seems to be quiet vague

Comment: Datatable generalServicesTable and removing through index value and below is the sample code which i am using now.                                                                        $ajax({
 url : url,
 async : false,
 success : function(response) {
            $("#generalServicesTable tbody tr").eq(index).find('.deleteStatus').val("InActive");
             $("#generalServicesTable tbody tr").eq(index).remove(); 
},
              error : function() {
             }
             });
           return false;

Comment: Remove the item from the array instead of using JQuery to remove the row.Then reinitialize the datatable again.

Comment: Can you share me some example for this process

Comment: You need to update your question. Add the code you mentionned in your comment to the question via a snippet and expand the list of tags. `datatable` as only tag is very vague, when you consider that multiple programming languages have a `datatable` concept. For example, you might want to add `jquery`.

Comment: As Stanislas suggested please add the code you've used to remove the datatable row

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Code:

```
 var dtRow=0;  //declare this globally
 dtRow = $(this).closest('tr');  //assigning value on click delete
 //add this in yes click
 var table=$('#table').DataTable();
 table.row(dtRow).remove().draw( false );
```